# Third-party (NPoco) package in ASP5 MVC6 says DNX Core 5 - Not Available

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm Trying to port **WebAPI2 to MVC6** but I've run in to the following obstacle everywhere.

Hovering over the missing reference gives me a dialog box saying:

```
DNX 4.5.1 - Available
DNX Core 5 - Not Available
```

I guess i needs to be available in both frameworks but how. 
When i look under references its there under both DNX versions.

Is it because of incompatibility with ASP5 and the package needs a newer version or something?

The dependencies i have are:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
"NPoco": "2.8.99-beta"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe i solved it myself by removing:

```
"dnxcore50": { }
```

from project.json

but is i not possible to have both...?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably NPoco has not produced a version that is compatible with .NET Core. Therefore it will only build for .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I guess you have to either wait for NPoco to produce a .NET Core version, or download the source and try to create your own.